# Command failed (cv php:boot --level=settings) when trying to run tests

Tags: developer, testing

I'm trying to run CiviCRM's unit tests, but I hit on this error when running scripts/phpunit AllTests:

```
RuntimeException: Command failed (cv php:boot --level=settings) in ...tests\phpunit\CiviTest\bootstrap.php
```

This is on the master branch of CiviCRM on a local development machine.

- Using Windows 7 with a XAMPP stack
- PHP Version 5.6.15
- The civicrm-core directory is up to date with the master branch

Comment: Hi John - can you please add some details on you dev environment;

Comment: Sorry, I should know better, I've done that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you install and use buildkit:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit

It comes with lots of tools - including those you need to run tests.

I use it on MAMP but from what I understand this will work on Windows as well.

Alternatively - if you like you can also:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit-vagrant

Comment: Yup, it works OK on vagrant. Buildkit is good but I've had some trouble getting it up and running on Windows. I'm also not sure if the cv package runs well on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding some steps to check if basic things are met correctly.

1. Make sure you are in civicrm folder when you run the test.

   ```
   $ cd <site_name>/sites/all/modules/civicrm
   $ export CIVICRM_UF=UnitTests
   $ phpunit4 tests/phpunit/api/v3/ContactTest.php
   ```
2. Is your **civicrm.settings.php** file searchable? Add the below line to your `~/.bash_profile` file.

   ```
   export CIVICRM_SETTINGS=/Users/jitendra/www/civicrm-master/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php
   ```
3. If you have cv installed and `cv vars:fill` runs fine, check if `civicrm.settings.php` values are correct($civicrm_root, CMS_DSN etc).

Answer (score 0):

cv is a command line tool that's not included with CiviCRM. The repo can be found here: https://github.com/civicrm/cv

This command line utility seems to be required to run phpunit tests in Civi. (Though I'm not sure yet whether it runs on Windows systems).